# Error in VB.NET + MYSQL + CRUD in my project

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp, crud

Hi Im working on a crud project and I have an error Showing a message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in VbMySQL_SMART_CRUD.exe

and the yellow area poiting to this :  sql = "SELECT auto_id, first_name, last_name, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS 'full_name', gender FROM tbl_smart_crud" &
"WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE @keyword1 OR gender = @keyword2 ORDER BY auto_id ASC"

Here is the full code and tell me what is wrong here please:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private ID As String = ""
    Private intRow As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As 
EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ResetMe()
        LoadData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetMe()

        Me.ID = ""
        FirstNameTextBox.Text = ""
        LastNameTextBox.Text = ""


        If GenderComboBox.Items.Count > 0 Then
            GenderComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If

        UpdateButton.Text = "Update()"
        DeleteButton.Text = "Delete()"

        KeywordTextBox.Clear()
        KeywordTextBox.Select()

    End Sub

Private Sub Execute(Mysql As String, Optional Parameter As String = "")
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(Mysql, con)
    Addparameters(Parameter)
    performcrud(cmd)
End Sub


Private Sub Addparameters(str As String)
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", FirstNameTextBox.Text.Trim())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", LastNameTextBox.Text.Trim())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", GenderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())

    If str = "Update" Or str = "Delete" And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ID) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Me.ID)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub InsertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InsertButton.Click

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstNameTextBox.Text.Trim()) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastNameTextBox.Text.Trim()) Then
        MsgBox("Por Favor Escreva As Informaçoes Em Falta. ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation,
               "Nova Estrela - Dados Do Produto")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_smart_crud(first_name, last_name, gender) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Gender)"

    Execute(sql, "Insert")

    MsgBox("Muito Obrigado... O registro Acima Foi Salvo Com Exito! ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information,
            "Nova Estrela - Dados Do Produto")

    LoadData()

    ResetMe()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadData(Optional keyword As String = "")


    sql = "SELECT auto_id, first_name, last_name, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS 'full_name', gender FROM tbl_smart_crud" &
     "WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE @keyword1 OR gender = @keyword2 ORDER BY auto_id ASC"

    Dim strKeyword As String = String.Format("%{0}%", keyword)

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("keyword1", strKeyword)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("keyword2", keyword)

    Dim dt As DataTable = performcrud(cmd)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        intRow = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString())
    Else
        intRow = 0
    End If

    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Numero De Registro(s): " & intRow.ToString()

    With DataGridView1

        .MultiSelect = False
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True


        .DataSource = dt

        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "FirstName"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "LastName"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "FullName"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Preco De Compra"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Gender"

        .Columns(0).Width = 85
        .Columns(0).Width = 170
        .Columns(0).Width = 170
        .Columns(0).Width = 220
        .Columns(0).Width = 100

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    Try

        Dim dgv As DataGridView = DataGridView1

        If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then

            Me.ID = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value).Trim()
            UpdateButton.Text = "Update(" & Me.ID & ")"
            DeleteButton.Text = "Delete(" & Me.ID & ")"

            FirstNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value).Trim()
            LastNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value).Trim()

            GenderComboBox.SelectedItem = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value).Trim()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ID) Then
        MsgBox("Por Favor Escolha Um Produto ou Artigo Na Lista.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation,
                "Nova Estrela - Actualizando Dados Do Produto")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstNameTextBox.Text.Trim()) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastNameTextBox.Text.Trim()) Then
        MsgBox("Por Favor Escreva As Informaçoes Em Falta. ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation,
               "Nova Estrela - Actualizando Dados Do Produto")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sql = "Update tbl_smart_crud Set first_name = @FirstName, last_name = @LastName, gender = @Gender WHERE auto_id = @ID"

    Execute(sql, "Update")

    MsgBox("O registro Acima Foi Actualizado Com Exito!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information,
            "Nova Estrela - Actualizando Dados Do Produto")

    LoadData()

    ResetMe()

End Sub

Private Sub DeleteButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteButton.Click

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ID) Then
        MsgBox("Por Favor Escolha Um Produto ou Artigo Na Lista.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation,
                "Nova Estrela - Apagando Dados e Registro Do Produto")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    If MessageBox.Show("Queres Mesmo Deletar O Registro Seleccionado?", "Nova Estrela - Apagando Dados e Registro Do Produto",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = DialogResult.Yes Then


        sql = "DELETE FROM add_product WHERE Codigo Do Produto = @Codigo Do Produto"

        Execute(sql, "Delete")

        MsgBox("O registro Foi Apagado Com Exito. ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information,
                "Nova Estrela - Apagando Dados e Registro Do Produto")

        LoadData()

        ResetMe()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(KeywordTextBox.Text.Trim()) Then
        LoadData(KeywordTextBox.Text.Trim())
    Else
        LoadData()
    End If

    ResetMe()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I guess you gave us the code for the entire program. You failed to provide the performcrud method. At any rate we only need the code where the error occurred. Try adding `Private sql As String = ""` where the other form level variables are. I am sorry to say that there are many problems with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the variable `sql`

after `Private intRow As Integer = 0` write `Private sql As String = ""`

Or

before any
`sql = "something"` write `var sql = ""` or `var sql As String = ""`

Comment: Didnt worked my friend, it added 8 errors ( var not declared , Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses ) any other sugestion?